# how to solve Notice: Undefined variable: cart_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\istore\cart.php on line 6

Tags: php, mysql

**how to solve  Notice: Undefined index: cart_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\istore\cart.php on line 6**

```html
<?php
  require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/istore/core/init.php';
  include 'includes/category_head.php';
  include 'includes/cart-header.php';

  if($cart_id != ''){
   
    $cartQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id = '{$cart_id}'");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ);
    $items = json_decode($result['items'],true);
    $i = 1;
    $sub_total = 0;
    $item_count = 0;

  }
 ?>
```

Someone please help me to fix it.

Comment: Where is line number 6 in your code???

Comment: if($cart_id != ''){

Comment: Where you define `$cart_id`???

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: What's also odd is the mixing and matching of object-oriented style for `mysqli`, which I'd strongly recommend, with the old PHP 4 procedural style. The OO version is usually much more compact, reads better, and avoids a lot of simple mistakes caused by forgetting to supply the database or statement handle.

Comment: @Saty how to define $cart_id variable ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that your variable `$cart_id` is not defined.

Change your if-statement to the following:

```
if(isset($cart_id) && $cart_id != '')
```

With this, you first check if the variable is set, and if it's set you check if it isn't empty.

Documentation on `isset`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: where does it come from? You define a variable by assigning a value to it. like this: `$my_var = 5`. Now, `$my_var` is assigned. You just have to assign some value to `$cart_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try any one of the given two way:

```
if(isset($cart_id) && $cart_id != '')
```

**or**

```
if(@$cart_id != '')
```

The above code is don't show the warning